# How do i call a function that requires an argument on key press? Python

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am a beginner programmer, sorry if the answer is obvious. Any help is appreciated.
I am currently using `WIN.onkeypress()` to call functions but my `scroll_draw_col` function requires the argument `curr_draw_col`. I know `WIN.onkeypress()` can't pass arguments to their function. How do I call the `scroll_draw_col` function with `curr_draw_col` as an argument on keypress ("f")?

```
def scroll_draw_col(curr_draw_col):
    curr_draw_col += 1


WIN.listen()
WIN.onkeypress(tri_fwd, 'Up')  # Unrelated
WIN.onkeypress(tri_bkw, 'Down')  # Unrelated

WIN.onkeypress(tri_left, 'Left')  # Unrelated
WIN.onkeypress(tri_right, 'Right')  # Unrelated

WIN.onkeypress(scroll_draw_col, 'f')  # <-----

while True:
    WIN.update()
    dra.goto(tri.xcor(), tri.ycor())  # Unrelated
    print(curr_draw_col)  # To see if curr_draw_col is being incremented by 1
```

Comment: Your `scroll_draw_col` function **does not** change the caller's input; if I write `a=3` and then `scroll_draw_col(a)`, then my `a` **does not** change. If you wanted to change a global, then it is neither necessary nor useful to pass it in as a parameter. Instead you want to use the `global` statement so that Python knows you are using the global variable.

Comment: Since you are using this call to change the state of the variable it might be a better idea to use a class.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `global` and remove the argument altogether. However, for future reference, you can pass an argument to a function without running it by using `lambda`:

```py
# What you should do
def scroll_draw_col():
    global curr_draw_col
    curr_draw_col += 1


WIN.listen()
WIN.onkeypress(tri_fwd, 'Up')  # Unrelated
WIN.onkeypress(tri_bkw, 'Down')  # Unrelated

WIN.onkeypress(tri_left, 'Left')  # Unrelated
WIN.onkeypress(tri_right, 'Right')  # Unrelated

WIN.onkeypress(scroll_draw_col, 'f')  # <-----

while True:
    WIN.update()
    dra.goto(tri.xcor(), tri.ycor())  # Unrelated
    print(curr_draw_col)  # To see if curr_draw_col is being incremented by 1 

# If you wanted to pass an argument on a key press
WIN.onkeypress(lambda: function_name(argument), 'f')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure Lecdi's answer is sufficient but I thought I might add a couple more methods.
It looks like what you are trying to do with this function call is change some state, increment a variable. For this, there are two techniques I'd suggest. For your particular use case, I would suggest a class.

```
class DrawColTrack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.col = 0
    def increment(self):
        self.col+=1


draw_col_tracker = DrawColTrack()

WIN.listen()
WIN.onkeypress(tri_fwd, 'Up')  # Unrelated
WIN.onkeypress(tri_bkw, 'Down')  # Unrelated

WIN.onkeypress(tri_left, 'Left')  # Unrelated
WIN.onkeypress(tri_right, 'Right')  # Unrelated

WIN.onkeypress(draw_col_tracker.increment, 'f')  # <-----

while True:
    WIN.update()
    dra.goto(tri.xcor(), tri.ycor())  # Unrelated
    print(draw_col_tracker.col)  # To see if curr_draw_col is being incremented by 1
```

The other way which I think is worth mentioning on the topic of lambdas etc is to create a closure.

```
def gen_col_incrementer(starting_value):
    def _():
       starting_value+=1
       return starting_value
    return _
increment = gen_col_incrementer(0)
assert 1 == increment()
```